# iOS - Intents eligible for in-app handling not work

Tags: ios, swiftui, shortcut, ios14, sirishortcuts

I have an application with a deployment target on iOS 14 and built entirely with swiftui.
I have added an intentdefinition file and added a couple of intents with their respective handlers, and I have added to my app delegate the function to handle them:

```
struct ...App: App {
 
 @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
...
}

extension AppDelegate {
 
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, handlerFor intent: INIntent) -> Any? {
     switch intent {
     case is NewTaskIntent:
         return NewTaskHandler()
     case is TodayTasksIntent:
         return TodayTasksHandler()
     default:
         return nil
     }
 }
}
```

The problem is that this function is never called and when I run the shortcut from its app it always launches my app.
The info Plist contains the keys correctly:

```
<key>INIntentsSupported</key>
    <array>
        <string>NewTaskIntent</string>
        <string>TodayTasksIntent</string>
    </array>
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I already found the problem, in case it happens to anyone, this happens when you have the Enable Multiple Windows key in the info.plist is set to NO, changing it to YES already works correctly

Comment: Thank you ! This solved the issue I was having

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SwiftUI, try `onContinueUserActivity(_:perform:)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/oncontinueuseractivity(_:perform:)

Note: its first argument `activityType` is defined in your main app's `Custom iOS Target Properties` with `NSUserActivityTypes` key. This property seems to be generated by Xcode auto-ly.

Inspired by the "Step Six" in https://toolboxpro.app/blog/adding-shortcuts-to-an-app-part-four

---

However, it's quite wired that my `func application(_ application: UIApplication, handlerFor intent: INIntent) -> Any?` triggered yesterday, but makes no sense right now. Is it a 'feature'